# Why AdapterView.OnItemClickListener's onItemClick position is -ve value

Tags: android

I had an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`, which is attached to `AutoCompleteTextView`.

According to my Google Android Console crash report, I realize `position` method parameter can be -1 sometimes (Very rare).

```
private OnItemClickListener getMyOnItemClickListener() {
    return new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            ....
```

I was wondering, under what circumstance, `position` can be -1?

The device which is having this problem is

```
Android version 
Android 4.1

Device 
Galaxy Core (arubaslimss)
```